# Why is a substrate needed in growing $\rm GaN$?

Tags: experimental-physics, material-science, semiconductor-physics

Is the substrate a layer on which [$\rm GaN$ crystal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gallium_nitride) grows on? Is there a way to grow free-standing $\rm GaN$? Would the resultant crystal be full of defects?

Answer (score -1):

Crystal growth always needs a substrate. You need a template, which tells the atoms how to arrange. Ideally, the substrate would have the same crystal structure and lattice constant. Since GaN substrates were technologically different to realize, growth on sapphire or Si(111) was studied.

A special case for GaN growth is called lateral epitaxial overgrowth, where an oxide mask prevents growth in large areas and allows only growth in between. For proper conditions, GaN first fills up the holes and then overgrows the mask and great s a virtual GaN substrate with lower defect densities.

Comment: What about using GaN seed crystals to grow larger "free-standing" crystals? I'm not sure if this is something that is feasible, but if so, it might answer the OP's second question.

Comment: Such bulk crystal growth is usually performed from melt. I'm not an absolute expert regarding III-N materials, but I'm guessing that the high vapor pressure of N would be the limiting factor here. You somehow need to maintain a melt of Ga and N. I'm not saying, this won't work at all. In fact, there are a few institutes/companies in the world that can do it. Though to my knowledge not yet with a quality comparable to conventional semiconductors (Si, Ge, III-V's).